# How to calculate mutual information

Tags: r, information-retrieval

I want to calculate term co-occurrence information in R. I'm trying to do with mutual information, i retrieved all the terms and its IDF . To calculate term co-occurrence how to or what input is to be given and how the calculation is being done for mutual information. 
For this I have taken Bigram terms
I'm beginner for this information systems, Even its a simple or basic question I couldn't understand how to proceed further
terms :

[image]

Bigrams :

[image]

To calculate this term Co-occurrence 
In R I tried to use qdapTools , tm  and entropy packages but I'm unable to understand how is this calculation is done what input should be provided to process this.
I dont know whether my procedure id correct or not

Comment: what is *term co-occurrence*?

Comment: How frequently two terms are occurred together in a corpus is Tern Co-occurence

Comment: Please follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) to make a reproducible example. In addition please add the expected output. This will make it much easier for others to help you. Also please post your own attempts and explain where exactly you got stuck.